# extract counting sorting and look-up

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I have a dataset with a rowID and a column 'items' that contains numbers delimited with commas.
Each number represents a specific item.
"1" stands for "B" and so on.

For each row, I want to calculate the individual weignt of each item.
To illustrate :
`"1,18,18,1"` or `"18,18,1,1"` has an equivalent weight than `"18,1"`, `"1,18"`, etc. with 1 and 18 valuing 50% of the weight.

The goal is to retrieve the final weigh into an output variable that will contain the "B" in wase  100% of the weight of item "1" in row. The 100% is the easiest case. When having 25% of "6" (which stands for "T") , 50 % of "1" (which stands for "B") and 25 % of "5" (which stands for "C") I want to get "TBCB" in the output final variable .

So far, I have created en column 'comp' that counts the numbers ("items") delimited by the commas in the "items" column.

I've created a % column representing the weight of each item.

My difficulty is to handle the final variable  : assembling the percentages so as to create the new sequence.

```
library(dplyr)library(stringr)

df = data.frame(
items =c(as.character("1,1,8,16,8,18,18,1,16,2,8,5,1","2,1,2,1,6"), 
as.character("18,18,19,18,4"), as.character("1,19,2"),   
as.character("2,2,2,4,2,6,1" )  , as.character("6,2,2") ,
ID = seq(1:5)
)
```

```
df1 <- df %>%mutate( comp = str_count(items, ",") + 1) %>%
  mutate (percentB = str_count(items , "1") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentM = str_count(items , "2") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentO = str_count(items , "3") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentAC = str_count(items , "4") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentC = str_count(items , "5") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentT = str_count(items , "6") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentPp = str_count(items , "18") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentPt = str_count(items , "19") / comp *100)
```

```
df2 <- df1 <- replace (items =case_when(percentPp  < 20  ~   gsub("^,|(?<=,),|,$", "" , str_remove_all(., "18"), perl =T)  %>%
  mutate( comp = str_count(items, ",") + 1) %>%mutate (percentB = str_count(items , "1") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentM = str_count(items , "2") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentO = str_count(items , "3") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentAC = str_count(items , "4") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentC = str_count(items , "5") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentT = str_count(items , "6") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentPp = str_count(items , "18") / comp *100) %>%
  mutate (percentPt = str_count(items , "19") / comp *100))

df3 <- df2 %>%
  mutate (lu =case_when (percentM  == 100 ~ "M",percentB  == 100 ~ "B",percentO  == 100 ~ "O",percentAC == 100 ~ "Ac",percentC  == 100 ~ "C",percentT  == 100 ~ "T",percentPp == 100 ~ "Pp",percentPt == 100 ~ "Pt",(percentB == 40) & (percentM == 40) & (percentT == 20) ~ "BBMMT")  %>%
  mutate( final = ifelse(. !=0 ~ gsub( "pourcent", "", cur_col(.)) , "" )))
```

I d like to automatize the copy (in the "final" column), the % of items by 1) descending of % and  when % are equal, then by 2) alphabetic order of items

Comment: code on RHS of attempt at creation of `df` is not complete. Please check that your code is correct and [edit] the question body .... NO comments responses.

Comment: I added line breaks after `%>%` to make your code more readable, but it could still use more formatting. And your sample data `df = ...` code has a syntax mistake so it doesn't run. Could you fix the syntax and maybe add more linebreaks so things are more readable?

Comment: If you add an extra `)` it runs but it still ignores the `"2,1,2,1,6"`..... was surprised it didn't throw an error

Comment: also,,, why would you want `"TBCB"`? Again ... clarifications in question body.